# Error: Could not find or load main

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-roo

i'm creating a SpringRoo Project in eclipse (STS), and run the project throw  Error: **Could not find or load main class src.main.java.com.ng.login.LogInApplication**

My project directory

[image]

---

My Spring Roo Log File

```
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MYSQL 
entity jpa --class ~.domain.LogIn
field string --fieldName username --notNull --sizeMax 5
field string --fieldName password --notNull --sizeMax 5
repository jpa --entity ~.domain.LogIn --interface ~.respository.LogInRespository
service --entity ~.domain.LogIn --repository ~.respository.LogInRespository --interface ~.service.LogInService --class ~.service.impl.LogInServiceImpl
web mvc setup
web mvc view setup --type THYMELEAF
web mvc controller --controller ~.web.LoginController --entity ~.domain.LogIn --service ~.service.LogInService --responseType THYMELEAF
perform eclipse
```

Please Help me. I'm **newbie** in Spring Roo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your project hasn't been loaded correctly by STS, as it is using the *src* folder as part of the java package: *src.main.java.com.ng.login.*.

It would be interesting to know the Spring Roo version and the steps you have performed to generate the project and load it into the STS.

Anyway, when the STS Spring Roo plugin is used the project is created and loaded in STS automatically [as explained in the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#using-spring-roo-create-boot-app), so I suppose you have created the project using the text console instead and then have imported the project in STS.

Also you have used the *perform eclipse* command, which is a way to call *mvn eclipse:eclipse* to generate the eclipse project. This command is deprecated, as nowadays the STS has support to load maven projects without using that utility.

If that's the case, try the following to solve the problem:

1. Remove the project in STS. When the confirmation dialog is shown, don't check the *Delete project contents on disk* option.
2. Look into your project root folder and delete any file or folder called *.project*, *.settings* or *.classpath*.
3. Open the *File* menu and select *Import*
4. In the *Import* dialog, open the *Maven* folder, select the *Existing maven projects* option and click *Next*
5. Browse to the root folder of the created project.
6. The *pom.xml* file of your project will appear, select it and then click the *Finish* button.

Comment: Sir @Cesar, i'm follow this your step it fine , but run this project throw this exception.  
**org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well**

Comment: To be able to compile java applications you have to use the Java JDK, which provides the java compiler, instead of the JRE. That's why the exception tells you to make sure you run the Eclipse/STS using a Java JDK, if it is run using a JRE maven won't be able to compile the project

Comment: Thank You Sir , Solve this my problem . Sir I watch your  Spring Roo related video in You tube,Very good explanation

Comment: Thanks! Please, remember to validate the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Spring roo generated the own **id**, but i'm mention the own **id** in class it throw the exception. Exception is **id** already define in test_Roo.aj

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. Please provide more information, sample code, the stack trace, ... 
Anyway, is this comment related to this answer or question?